# Inserting an empty option box at the top of dynamically created select box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using [Select Box from antd](https://ant.design/components/select/). In the following snippet, I dynamically create the `Option` in the select box and return to be part of the array named `analyticalMethodtOptions`.

```
let analyticalMethodtOptions =
  analyticalMethods &&
  analyticalMethods.map((aM, i) => (
    <Option key={i} value={aM.id}>
      {aM.name}
    </Option>
  ));
```

Now, I also want to add an empty `Option` bar at the top that does not have any value and set that to default. How could I do this?

I want to insert an empty option bar like:

```
<Option value=""></Option>
```

at the top of `analyticalMethodtOptions` so that the empty item is available at the top of select box.

I am using it later to render the select box as:

```
  <Select
            placeholder="Select the Analytical Method"
            showSearch={true}
            filterOption={selectSearchFilter}
            defaultValue=""
          >
            {analyticalMethodtOptions}
   </Select>
```

Comment: This is a placeholder right? Which is supported by that component after looking at their docs.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Have added the render snippet for select box

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Try adding: `value={undefined}` as a prop, or `defaultValue={undefined}` using `""` will override it

Comment: Perhaps `allowClear` is what you're looking for https://ant.design/components/select/#Select-props

Answer (score 0):

Declare an array and push one entry with empty value.

```
var selectOptions = [];
    selectOptions.push({
        id: 'default',
        name: ''
    });
```

And copy the entries of analyticalMethodtOptions to above declared array "selectOptions"

```
selectOptions = selectOptions.concat(analyticalMethods);
```

Then

```
selectOptions = selectOptions.map((aM, i) => (
            <Option key={i} value={aM.id}>
                {aM.name}
            </Option>
        ));
```

Then in render

```
<Select>
    {selectOptions}
</Select>
```

Comment: as the value is "" (empty) , there will be little space to select it, consider adding "None" or "Default" or "Select" in place of empty value.